# What does set standardElementConstraints = false do?

Tags: orientdb

I have embedded OrientDB inside my Java application but have run in to some problems after this. Creating an Edge with null properties fails, but works after running

```
ALTER DATABASE SET standardElementConstraints = false
```

This is supposed to "change the setting to apply the Blueprints standard constraints against elements", but I can't find any documentation of what these standard constraints actually are.

What am I actually disabling by doing this?

Comment: should be ALTER DATABASE CUSTOM standardElementConstraints = false

Answer (score 1):

You're only disabling Blueprints checks, like property with name 'id' and few other things, but don't worry, this doesn't break OrientDB in any way.